# Grab header name of all max values

Tags: excel

So I have a formula that finds the max value in a row and grabs the header name of the column.

The problem is if I have a row with 2 of the the same max value it only grabs the name of the first one.

Is it possible to grab all headers with the same max value with a formula?

Here is what I am using.

```
=INDEX(Header,0,MATCH(MAX($D2:$BV2),$D2:$BV2,0))
```

Comment: There are many different ways, but it depends on your version and whether you want the output in one cell or many?  If many, is the output horizontal or vertical?  If one, how do you want it delimited?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was thinking one cell. Comma delimited.

Comment: What version do you have? Are you using Office 365?

Comment: I am using excel 2013

Comment: Then you will need VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the list in one cell, if one has the Dynamic Array formulas:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(Header,MAX($D2:$BV2)=$D2:$BV2))
```

If one does not have the Dynamic Array formula then we need to use VBA.  There are many TEXTJOIN UDF's out there.  Here is mine:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Then one would call it using:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(MAX($D2:$BV2)=$D2:$BV2,Header,""))
```

And confirm it as an array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.